# What is the name of the hinge that pops out a few inches, then swings open

Tags: doors, hinges

I'm trying to determine the name of the type of hinge that when actuated pops outwards (or inwards) before allowing the object it's attached to to rotate open.

The only examples I can think of that demonstrate the motion are all from sci-fi/games with the closest real world example being the sliding door on a minivan, which pops outwards as it starts to slide open.

**Edit** - More detailed description of actuation.

User grabs handle and pulls the door/lid towards themselves several inches, upon reaching maximum extent, door/lid is/can then be swung open in the traditional manner.

I may need to just self fabricate by welding an Extend Tip Out hinge to a traditional side hinge to get the actuation behavior.

*Edit** - Video
An answer identified the type of door as a 'plug door', using that I found a video that shows the motion I was describing, except the airplane door pops in before going out and I was thinking pop out before rotating out. [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PLxwNv6Y3C0&t=1m40s)

Still searching for the hinge itself that allows this motion. Fancy aerospace pressurization effects (or cost) not desired.

Comment: I don't think the hinge pops out, the framing moves out. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Could you provide a photo of this (other than a minivan) I can only think of the magnetic latches that when pushed they pop out and allow the door to be pulled open.

Comment: @JACK I'm wanting to build a sci-fi inspired cabinet, and was hoping there was existing hardware that would actuate in the desired manner. not knowing the name for such an actuation made it difficult to google.
Edit added with more description of actuation.

Comment: There are  kitchen cabinet hinges that combine an outward motion with a rotation to allow full 180-degree opening around adjacent doors.   There are some cargo vans I've seen where the rear doors are on double hinges, the combined effect of which is to move the doors out and to the side while they rotate so they can be opened 270 degrees flush with the sides of the van.  There are hinges like on old TV cabinets where the door swings open then slides into the cabinet.  There are parallelogram hinges where the door moves out then sideways rather than actually rotating.   What are you seeking?

Comment: @jay613 your mention of parallelogram hinge is close. (googling it more now) Is there a variant of that where it's combined with a rotating hinge? In computer programming I'd translate the door forward by X, then once clear of any obstructions, rotate to the left by Y.

Comment: The parallel hinge I'm thinking of does not rotate.   It translates outward then translates up or sideways.   When it's mounted vertically it's called a Swing Lift Hinge. EG https://www.walmart.com/ip/Cabinet-Door-Vertical-Swing-Lift-Up-Stay-Pneumatic-Arm-Kitchen-Mechanism-Hinge/856760124.     I can't visualize what you mean by translate then rotate.  What's the point of the translation?  How is it better than a simple hinge?  What obstruction?

Comment: I built some cabinets with such hinges.  Unfortunately we've downsized since then, so I can't look at the brand.  I remember that I had to try several stores in town to find them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a plug door.

Not just for aircraft, they are also used on railway and transit vehicles to reduce loading gage.

Comment: Yes, this led me to the pressurized cabin door of an old 747 that opened outwards the way I was thinking. Now to determine the hinge type used and track that down. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PLxwNv6Y3C0 1:45-1:49)

Comment: @Reahreic I do hope you find one commercially available, but do be aware that plug-door hinges are generally bespoke items designed specifically for each aircraft. There a non-zero chance that you _won't_ find what you're after commercially. It sounds like you've got metal fab skills, so you may have to settle for making one by duplicating what you see in the aircraft door videos. It would be great if you posted an answer showing what you do come up with - it would be helpful for others in the future!

Comment: @FreeMan there are cabinet hinges that have a "semi-plug" behavior.  I would start my search at a really good old hardware store that has drawers and drawers and drawers of cabinet hinges.

Comment: This is a good clarifying comment that provides an example of the desired real-world behavior better than the OP’s original minivan example, but what is the answer to the question itself?

Answer (score 2):

A lateral hinge makes that type of movement. Comes out and then to the side.

Also called lateral opening hinge.